# Viber бот PHP - как отключить ограничение по возрасту?

Tags: php, бот, viber

Из глубокой ссылки на бота пытаюсь передать параметр.
viber://pa?chatURI=&context=params&text=Start
При переходе по ссылке открывается чат с ботом но в файле обработчике не происходит никаких событий для отправки приветственного сообщения. Подозреваю что проблема в ограничении по возрасту (18+), которое установлено по умолчанию и я не могу его отключить (переключатель не реагирует)!
Не понимаю почему. Помогите!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У меня тоже не получилось убрать галочку. Подозреваю что это нельзя сделать, т.к при регистрации вы отметили, что бот содержит контент для взрослых

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написал в тех поддержку и они сняли галку)

Answer (score 0):

Это можно исправить, отключив adult ограничения.

Заходите в Viber на телефоне (с которого создан канал):

- Меню "Еще" - >
- "Настройки" - >
- "Мои чат-боты" - >
- выбираете свой чат-бот - >
- нажимаете кнопку "Изменить" - >
- листаете вниз и деактивируете ограничения по возрасту.

Answer (score 0):

придется только нового создавать..
вот хорошая инструкция, если что
https://saltpro.ru/articles/podklyuchenie-viber-v-bitriks24/

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)